# Point example.com back to webhost, stop using Github pages?

Tags: domains, dns

I'd like to point my domain back to my webhost after having used it in a Github pages repository. I remember having to set A records to point said `example.com` to `example.github.io` but now I'd like to point it back to my webhost.

What's the best way to do this? Should I just delete the A records and wait for things to resolve?

So far I tried doing this put initial checking seems to return a server error, and I don't know exactly where the domain is pointing now. A `dig` command in terminal returns the nameserver of my webhost, but I think there's a misconfiguration.

Pingdom checker returned this message:

> The name server failed to answer queries sent over TCP. This is probably due to the name server not correctly set up or due to misconfgured filtering in a firewall. It is a rather common misconception that DNS does not need TCP unless they provide zone transfers - perhaps the name server administrator is not aware that TCP usually is a requirement.

As a side note, I have set a couple of subdomains on GH pages also, but since they're subdomains their DNS settings shouldn't affect top-level, right?

Answer (score 1):

You will need the IP address of your web host and change the A record to that.

You likely have two A records currently `192.30.252.153` & `192.30.252.154` (for github), be sure to delete one and edit the other.

If you leave the A records alone for the subdomains they should be OK.

To confirm that your DNS record is set up correctly, use the dig command with your domain  `$ dig +noall +answer example.com`